# codeigniter POST dynamic data

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem with posting dynamic text box data with code-igniter. I am going to do this using insert_batch() method.

view

```
<input name="qty[]" type="text" id="qty[]" size="5" maxlength="5" />
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" id="id[]" value="<?php echo  $v_items->product_id ; ?>"  />
```

In controller I have get array result like this;

```
public function submit_in()
        {

              $data = array(
                 'id' => $this->input->post('qty'),
                  'qty' => $this->input->post('id')
                );

             $data['title'] = 'Damage Product';
             $data['subview'] = $this->load->view('admin/cwh/stock_in', $data, true);
             $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $data);

        } 


array (size=3)
  'id' => 
    array (size=13)
      0 => string 'qw' (length=2)
      1 => string 'qw' (length=2)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string 'qwqw' (length=4)
      4 => string '' (length=0)
      5 => string '' (length=0)
      6 => string 'q' (length=1)
      7 => string '' (length=0)
      8 => string 'wwq' (length=3)
      9 => string '' (length=0)
      10 => string '' (length=0)
      11 => string '' (length=0)
      12 => string 'qw' (length=2)
  'qty' => 
    array (size=13)
      0 => string '74' (length=2)
      1 => string '75' (length=2)
      2 => string '76' (length=2)
      3 => string '77' (length=2)
      4 => string '78' (length=2)
      5 => string '79' (length=2)
      6 => string '80' (length=2)
      7 => string '81' (length=2)
      8 => string '82' (length=2)
      9 => string '83' (length=2)
      10 => string '84' (length=2)
      11 => string '85' (length=2)
      12 => string '86' (length=2)
  'title' => string 'Damage Product' (length=14)
```

So i cant perform batch_insert() method using this array result. (I think my array result format is wrong)

My table structure is

```
product_data(**pid**,id,qty);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manipulate your data before use

```
$this->db->insert_batch('my_table',$data);
```

This is my suggestion:

```
$arr_qty = $this->input->post('qty');
$arr_id  = $this->input->post('id');

$i=-1;
foreach($arr_qty as $qty):
$i++;
    $data[] = array(
                        'qty' => $qty,
                        'id'  => $arr_id[$i]
                   );
endforeach;

// Then

$this->db->insert_batch('my_table',$data);
```

Tell me if it works.

Comment: you may use `if(!empty($arr_qty))`

Answer (score 0):

bulk insert you must loop in order to insert the bulk data

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_POST['name']);$i++)
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];

     $data = array(
                   $name[$i];
                  );
     // insert the query here for insert



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually **you assign wrong data**

```
'id' => $this->input->post('qty'),//Wrong 'qty'
'qty' => $this->input->post('id') //wrong 'id'
```

`ID ==QTY` and `QTY == ID`

That is **wrong in your code, *It should be***

```
'id' => $this->input->post('id'), //correct
'qty' => $this->input->post('qty') //correct
```